# What is the best way to encrypt data in an application

Tags: security, encryption, rsa

I am trying to find the best way/practice for having a resource file shipped to a user as cipher text. And decrypt these cipher in the software itself:

- I have an XML file containing data.
- I don't want the user to be able to read this file.
- I use RSA algorithm to encrypt/decrypt the data
- I want the software to be able to decrypt the file and read it like it would with a plain text file.

So far, I was thinking about having the private key stored as a string in the application, and the public key distributed in a file alongside with the executable.

My concern is: is it secure, and is there other practice that would be better in this kind of case?

Comment: There are countless encyption solutions easily found with google

Comment: There is plenty of solutions for users to encrypt their data, or for developer to implement encryption/decryption solutions. But there is not much about software development practices.

Comment: This site isn't for regurgitating best practices. It is for specific problems, not "what is the best way...." questions.

Answer (score 1):

No, it's not. Nothing stops the user from extracting the private key from the executable or from extracting the decrypted data from memory.

There may be a solution given the detailed specifics of your use case, but the general problem is provably unsolvable. The user has the software. The software has everything it needs to decrypt. Therefore, the user has everything they need to decrypt.